# Error: invalid json with multer and body-parser

Tags: json, node.js, form-data, body-parser, multer

I am currently using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for `multipart/form-data` in node.js application alongside with [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

I tried to **POST** form-data using POSTMAN, but it is getting this error.

```
Error: invalid json
    at parse (/Users/k/Documents/application/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:79:15)
    at /Users/k/Documents/application/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:102:18
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/k/Documents/application/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:136:7)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

This is how I added multer and body-parser in my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}));
```

I think it is probably because multer is not working. When I remove body-parser and try again, it shows empty json for `console.log(req.body)` and `console.log(req.files)`.

Note: `body-parser` version is **1.12.0** and `multer` version is **0.1.8**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is not that you have both libraries `body-parser` and `multer`. If you try to post with a browser extension like postman, please make sure `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data` and not `application/json` in your request header.

Comment: Use "multipart/form-data"

Comment: How to achieve it with application/json ?