# Monitoring & Analytics Causes App to Crash

Tags: node.js, monitoring, ibm-cloud

Has anyone had problems with adding Monitoring and Analytics as a service and causing #bluemix apps to crash? I have a NodeJS app and as soon as I added M&A, the app will no longer load.

Thanks.

It looks like it's crashing because of an error in POST with mongoose. I'm looking at it right now on whether it is just mongoose or how Bluemix is handling the error. I've found a few github discussions:

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3391
[Error: invalid json with multer and body-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006170/error-invalid-json-with-multer-and-body-parser)

```
    2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:58
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR at model._next (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:58:23)
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1721:23
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR throw new Error("Your pre must have a next argument -- e.g., f
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR ^
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR at model.proto.(anonymous function) [as $__original_save] (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:108:20)
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERRError: Your pre must have a next argument -- e.g., function (next, ...)
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR at model.wrappedPointCut [as save] (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1703:14)
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR at Query.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/controllers/users.js:173:18)
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR at new Promise.ES6 (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:45:3)
2015-11-12T15:35:02.722-0500[App/0]ERR at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

I don't know if this should be crashing the entire instance. Shouldn't Bluemix be more resilient?

Comment: Can you paste the output from the $ cf logs APP_NAME command?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, even yours is not a bad question, I suggest this kind of question and situations to be asked on either official site issues / bugs or Google Groups

Comment: Please report your application logs: you could retrieve these using cf logs (appname) --recent. 
Otherwise I suggest you to ask for support to Bluemix support team following the instructions you find here ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/getting_customer_support.html.
You will be asked for application logs, the same I suggested to report here

Comment: Logs have been posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added error handing to next event. We need to get Bluemix to dump errors instead of crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using free plan or diagnostics plan? If you are using diagnostics plan, you might need a larger Memory (my suggestion is 1G by now), because the diagnostics plan generated huge data.

If you are using free plan, then you might need to check the push application way. 

For Node.js, you might need to write a file which name is **Procfile** which content is the command line you run the application:
here is an example:

```
web: node app.js
```

In **packages.json**, scripts field is also required:
here is an example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
},
```

In **manifest.yml**, you should add the M&A Services's name
here is an example:

```
applications:
- disk_quota: 1024M
  host: xxxx
  name: xxxx
  path: .
  domain: xxxx.mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 1024M
  services:
  - Monitoring and Analytics-xxx
  - mongodb-xx
```

After complete these three changes, please delete your previous application first, then push it again:
first:

```
cf delete <appname>
```

then:

```
cf push
```

If these cannot make your application works, please feel free to contact me.

Comment: Yup, I was using diagnostics and the app was running at 1024. It would stage and the upon first execution or GET command, it would crash. I'm going to try your solution and report back.

Comment: @JustinSaadein I would like to have some debug on your application, do you mind send me your app? If you have any confidential codes could you please simplify your application package and make sure the problem is still exist.

Comment: How do I contact you? We can chat offline.

Comment: My email that bond with stackoverflow is: xiaoshimimi@hotmail.com, you can send mail to me.